# MVC5 ASP.NET Identity 2 Email Confirmation

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

MVC5 ASP.NET Identity2 out of the box implementation for email verification following registration creates a  code  like below - (I am using Int Id and MySQL)

```
   var code = await userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("confirmation", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code}, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

I then send email using mvcmailer which works as expected

```
await UserMailer.RegistrationConfirm(user.Id,  user.LastName, user.FirstName, callbackUrl).SendAsync();
```

The generated confirmation url never touches the route I have put this at the top off all others

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "confirmaccount",
           "account/confirmation/{userId}-{code}",
            new { controller = "Account", action = "confirmation"},
             new { userId = @"\d+" }); // URL Constraints );
```

I do not know what might be wrong here.  Does anyone have a shorter alternative of confirming email? The generated Url looks very ugly as well
example is as below:

```
http://localhost:56914/account/confirmation/34-ezqSkgYQmZ2Jpkib8WswHlmCCcBaYYhl21xzvhisWdSZtGPIP2hauUtT6Av7vt48hmdVZv2axFjCvQzMpyatMb3zQn8Ga50dAAeQ8OPgMoMM13vORp2TG8%2babTxTbXN51vdmfN7ESsdR3L5f9jWXUw%3d%3d
```

The best I get is a white blank page,  I wanted to know if I was missing something I really need this to work.

Comment: Try reading through http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity to see if you missed anything.

Comment: Thanks @AndresCastro - I have checked and solved the issue.  The problem is in the routemap and so  I enabled routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();